# Как обновить запись в php myadmin

Tags: mysql

У меня имеются столбцы с записями,как мне их обновить новым значениям, через Insert или update и пожалуйста приведите пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name SET col1 = value1 [, col2 = value2 ...] [WHERE where_definition]
```

Оператор UPDATE обновляет столбцы в соответствии с их новыми значениями в строках существующей таблицы. В выражении SET указывается, какие именно столбцы следует модифицировать и какие величины должны быть в них установлены. В выражении WHERE, если оно присутствует, задается, какие строки подлежат обновлению. В остальных случаях обновляются все строки.

**Пример:**

```
UPDATE users SET is_active = 0 WHERE user_id = 123;
```